# Take a JSON object from an expression and convert it into an association?

Tags: export, import, json-format

```
line = "[2015-09-09 10:30:59,712] [jfklein@wolfram.com] [t68981_103059] [INFO ] [http-8080-1] : API controller timing: UUID: a9612348-37ac-47a5-b8db-babc01201a65 times: {\"filters+Spring\":19.251555,\"handle cloud op\":12.771549,\"setup\":2.907936,\"create kernel request\":0.405042,\"init kernel\":0.121847,\"get init user config\":4.543503,\"set subscription info\":10.702821,\"config setup\":5.582888,\"eval user config\":37.670934,\"setup eval\":5.042273,\"eval WL controller\":141.478231,\"post-eval\":0.532579,\"commit response\":6.591477,\"finalize\":0.332402,\"_total\":247.937046,\"_keyOrder\":[\"filters+Spring\",\"handle cloud op\",\"setup\",\"create kernel request\",\"init kernel\",\"get init user config\",\"set subscription info\",\"config setup\",\"eval user config\",\"setup eval\",\"eval WL controller\",\"post-eval\",\"commit response\",\"finalize\",\"_total\",\"_keyOrder\",\"_category\",\"_label\",\"_startTime\"],\"_category\":\"APIEvaluation\",\"_label\":\"jfklein2win.wri.wolfram.com:1441812654004:1\",\"_startTime\":6571665880930982}"
```

Since I am new to Wolfram language it is difficult for me to understand how to perform this task.

Comment: As stated your question doesn't really conform to our standards for questions. Could you pose it more clearly with the question explicitly stated and indicate what you have tried? Also in general it's nice to have the code formatted. See the [help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for more.

Comment: @b3m2a1 please review the edited question and apologies for the confusion created earlier..

Comment: Try `ImportString[..., "RawJSON"]`

Comment: @b3m2a1 I think line is an expression . Hence ImportString will not work here. That's the first thing I tried also, The JSON part of line only starts at {\"filters+Spring....

Comment: I just tried it, and it worked... but you have to remove the non-JSON part from the string first. The JSON starts with `{\" filters+Spring \"`

Comment: The non JSON part can be deleted with `StringDelete[line,StartOfString ~~ Except["{"] ..]`