# List of Strings to Associations

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

I have a list of Strings, some thing like below:

```
{"\"filters+Spring\":19.251555", "\"handle cloud op\":12.771549", \
"\"setup\":2.907936", "\"create kernel request\":0.405042", "\"init \
kernel\":0.121847", "\"get init user config\":4.543503", "\"set \
subscription info\":10.702821", "\"config setup\":5.582888", "\"eval \
user config\":37.670934", "\"setup eval\":5.042273", "\"eval WL \
controller\":141.478231", "\"post-eval\":0.532579", "\"commit \
response\":6.591477", "\"finalize\":0.332402", \
"\"_total\":247.937046", "\"_keyOrder\":[\"filters+Spring\"", \
"\"handle cloud op\"", "\"setup\"", "\"create kernel request\"", \
"\"init kernel\"", "\"get init user config\"", "\"set subscription \
info\"", "\"config setup\"", "\"eval user config\"", "\"setup \
eval\"", "\"eval WL controller\"", "\"post-eval\"", "\"commit \
response\"", "\"finalize\"", "\"_total\"", "\"_keyOrder\"", \
"\"_category\"", "\"_label\"", "\"_startTime\"]", \
"\"_category\":\"APIEvaluation\"", \
"\"_label\":\"jfklein2win.wri.wolfram.com:1441812654004:1\"", \
"\"_startTime\":6571665880930982"}
```

I wanted to convert that into an Association that looks like:

```
<|"filters+Spring" -> 19.2516, "setup eval" -> 5.04227, 
 "init kernel" -> 0.121847, "handle cloud op" -> 12.7715, 
 "setup" -> 2.90794, "commit response" -> 6.59148, 
 "create kernel request" -> 0.405042, "finalize" -> 0.332402, 
 "get init user config" -> 4.5435, "set subscription info" -> 10.7028,
  "post-eval" -> 0.532579, "config setup" -> 5.58289, 
 "eval user config" -> 37.6709, "eval WL controller" -> 141.478, 
 "Total" -> 247.937|>
```

I am new to Mathematica, and not getting how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get those strings from?  I assume from a JSON file.  Do not try to parse the JSON manually. Use `Import[..., "JSON"]` instead (or `"RawJSON"`).

Comment: Please read here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingData.html http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/JSON.html http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/RawJSON.html

Comment: I extracted them from a log file in csv format

Comment: See the comments here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/177007/12

Answer (score 3):

This follows Szabolics advice in the comments.

First we assign your list of strings to `jsonStrings`:

```
jsonStrings = {"\"filters+Spring\":19.251555", 
   "\"handle cloud op\":12.771549", "\"setup\":2.907936", 
   "\"create kernel request\":0.405042", "\"init kernel\":0.121847", 
   "\"get init user config\":4.543503", 
   "\"set subscription info\":10.702821", "\"config setup\":5.582888",
    "\"eval user config\":37.670934", "\"setup eval\":5.042273", 
   "\"eval WL controller\":141.478231", "\"post-eval\":0.532579", 
   "\"commit response\":6.591477", "\"finalize\":0.332402", 
   "\"_total\":247.937046", "\"_keyOrder\":[\"filters+Spring\"", 
   "\"handle cloud op\"", "\"setup\"", "\"create kernel request\"", 
   "\"init kernel\"", "\"get init user config\"", 
   "\"set subscription info\"", "\"config setup\"", 
   "\"eval user config\"", "\"setup eval\"", "\"eval WL controller\"",
    "\"post-eval\"", "\"commit response\"", "\"finalize\"", 
   "\"_total\"", "\"_keyOrder\"", "\"_category\"", "\"_label\"", 
   "\"_startTime\"]", "\"_category\":\"APIEvaluation\"", 
   "\"_label\":\"jfklein2win.wri.wolfram.com:1441812654004:1\"", 
   "\"_startTime\":6571665880930982"};
```

Then make an association of the results of `ImportString`:

```
Association@
 ImportString["{" <> StringRiffle[jsonStrings, ","] <> "}", "JSON"]

(*
<|"filters+Spring" -> 19.2516, "handle cloud op" -> 12.7715, 
 "setup" -> 2.90794, "create kernel request" -> 0.405042, 
 "init kernel" -> 0.121847, "get init user config" -> 4.5435, 
 "set subscription info" -> 10.7028, "config setup" -> 5.58289, 
 "eval user config" -> 37.6709, "setup eval" -> 5.04227, 
 "eval WL controller" -> 141.478, "post-eval" -> 0.532579, 
 "commit response" -> 6.59148, "finalize" -> 0.332402, 
 "_total" -> 247.937, 
 "_keyOrder" -> {"filters+Spring", "handle cloud op", "setup", 
   "create kernel request", "init kernel", "get init user config", 
   "set subscription info", "config setup", "eval user config", 
   "setup eval", "eval WL controller", "post-eval", "commit response",
    "finalize", "_total", "_keyOrder", "_category", "_label", 
   "_startTime"}, "_category" -> "APIEvaluation", 
 "_label" -> "jfklein2win.wri.wolfram.com:1441812654004:1", 
 "_startTime" -> 6571665880930982|>
*)
```

Comment: I assumed that these bits came from a failed attempt to parse a JSON file (which removed the `{` and `}`).  The best thing would be to use the original JSON source (instead of reconstructing it).  OP should clarify.

Comment: @Szabolcs Agreed. At this point using your comments and/or my answer OP should be able to clarify his question. (Since OP is a newcomer I wanted to provide additional help...)

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot, that worked perfectly.
Can you please explain, how it is working

Comment: You should refer to the documentation pages which @Szabolcs had shared in earlier comment. That should answer the how part.

Comment: I went through some of the docs, but could not find the relevant one.
I will check what @Szabolcs  has mentioned
Thanks a lot...